# How to use AWS cli in an docker image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I'm developing some micro services.
I use docker-compose for local testing and I deploy stuff to ECS via copilot.

One of the NodeJS services now requires AWS CLI.

What's the best way to add this?

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-buster-slim as base

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python build-essential curl unzip

RUN curl --insecure "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip
RUN ./aws/install

...

RUN npm install
```

The problem is that AWS CLI cannot find the credentials this way and therefore NPM install fails. How can make the credentials available?
I tried to add a volume to docker-compose.yml, but it didn't work.

Can I provide AWS config / credentials as ENV vars somehow? I can't run aws configure in the container, since it requires manual input.

EDIT:

Is there some simple solution? I basically need AWS CLI only because I need to run `aws codeartifact login`  so I can install private NPM packages.

I'm sure creating a task will solve this, isn't there a simpler way?
I do everything else via the AWS-SDK and I already have the credentials for that. But this step is required by NPM install, so I must use the CLI.

EDIT2:

Basically I need to run this in the build phase:

```
aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository xyz --domain something --region eu-west-1
```

We have private NPM repo using CodeArtiact. I need to login to use that. But Docker doesn't support ENV vars in Dockerfile, so I don't know how to provide AWS credentials.

Basically that's the only problem.

Comment: I find this question confusing. Do you just need to use the AWS CLI during the docker build? Or do you need to use it in the container when the container is running on ECS?

Comment: Yes! Sorry about the confusion. I need it only in the build phase, while npm install is running. I need to install private NPM packages.

Comment: @MarkB are you there?

Comment: This question is confusing to everyone because you included all this information about using ECS when that is totally irrelevant to the problem you are trying to solve. You are just trying to run the AWS CLI during the Docker build phase, it is irrelevant where the docker image will eventually be deployed. Just pass the AWS credentials as environment variables into the Docker build.

Comment: OK but how? Docker doesn't handle env vars during build. Or you mean I should pass them as build args?

Answer (score 2):

There are many options to supply credentials to the CLI. They are documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-precedence) with their precedence.

While I am not sure about your specific setup and the best approach with copilot I would try opting for the Environment variables option as it is well supported with docker-compose.

Similarly, the JS-SDK has a credentials chain (reference for V2 [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the info! Actually I need to install private npm packages during build phase and that's why I need the cli

Comment: So the only option is associating IAM role with my ECS container right? I mean, Docker doesn't support ENV vars, it cannot copy files from outside the context (so I can't copy ~/.aws/*)

Comment: The question in the comment isn't very clear to me. naturally you can COPY the the AWS credentials file if it exists. you will then bake the credentials into the docker image which is not very recommendable for security reasons. additionally in most use cases the permissions required in order to build the image (+ connect to private nom repos. etc) and the permissions the running application (ECS task) need differ much.